# VS Code Files in Staging area

Tags: git, github

I am not too sure what I have done, I am starting a new project, I have been using VS Code and Git for a while now on my laptop and I have not yet come across such a problem, my intial commit is full of files I have never seen or used, how do I remove these as the commands I know to reset the staging area etc are not removing these, these look like very important files,

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you git init your home folder "C:\Users\blood"

Comment: Sorry for the lack of experience, but how would i redo that?

Comment: The easiest way is go to the "C:\Users\blood" folder. Make sure you've hidden files enabled. And delete .git folder

Comment: Thank you so much man, i dont even know how i could have done that but I appreciate your helped, it worked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home